# load an event on a finished redirected page after an AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How do I load an event after a redirected page has finished loading, following an ajax call?

For the sake of simplicity, here is some sample code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some_page.php",
   success: function() {
      window.location.href="new_page.php"; // redirect to this page
      $(window).load(function() { alert("test"); }); // load after redirect
   }
});
```

the "alert" box does not load for me, but the redirect works.

Comment: Why are you posting to a page and then redirecting to it? Did you mean to make this an "AJAX" request to not cause a page refresh? In that case you'd have to take the resulting HTML and stick it in a div.

Comment: This is a very basic example of what I'm really trying to do, so for the sake of saving everyone from reading a bunch of unnecessary code, I put a really simple 8 line code to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish.  And for the record, no, I'm not trying to prevent a page refresh.

Comment: Why not just skip the AJAX part and do a normal POST to your server which can then redirect you to whatever page you want.

Comment: Since I stated earlier that this is a very basic example of the real problem I'm having, let me elaborate further for those who think this is the wrong approach.  I have this AJAX script going to one page, covering 9 different scenarios.  I've used the answer below to set a query string to cover each scenario instead.  I guess another solution that would pertain to your comment is to just make 9 different PHP pages to cover each scenario too--but at the time of the posting of the question, I was pressed for time and had to come up with a script that worked for a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because success only works after your http request returned successfully. The browser then reloads the new requested page in which any actions are regarding your original http request are lost.

You may want to do something like:

```
window.location.href = new_window.php?success=true
```

Then test for success on the newly loaded page.

Comment: ah, thanks for the explanation; I figured that was probably the case.  You saved me from pulling my hair out!